# XSL não entra na condição correta

Tags: xml, sharepoint, xslt

Eu tenho a seguinte condição:

```xml
<xsl:when test="$Rows[1]/@Style='Resultado-Lista'">
 <ul>
  <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
     <li>
        <a href="/{@FileRef}" title="{$Data} - {@Title}">
           <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test="(@PublishingRollupImage = '')">
               <img src="/Util/Imagens/Conteudo/sem-imagem-noticia.jpg" />
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="@PublishingRollupImage"  />
             </xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
        </a>
     </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </ul>
</xsl:when>
```

Em um dos resultados o campo `@PublishingRollupImage` está preenchido, porém sempre entra na primeira condição.

Utilizo uma lista de páginas do sharepoint para fazer a busca e o campo é do tipo "**Imagem de Publicação**"

Já tentei fazer com `xsl:if` porém, acredito que eu esteja fazendo a condição de forma errada. Alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Comment: Há varios fatores que podem fazer com que um elemento nao seja selecionado, dentre eles o contexto e namespaces. Por favor edite sua questao para incluir o XML fonte (ou um fragmento, que inclua a hierarquia e os elementos raiz) e também um template inteiro do seu XSL (se possivel o doc XSLT inteiro, ou pelo menos o inicio e os templates relevantes).

Comment: Exemplifiquei melhor. Espero que ajude. Retirei apenas algumas chamadas de variáveis que não influenciam no resultado final

Comment: O ideal seria ver o código XML. E mais do XSLT que mostre qual é o conteúdo da variável `$Rows` já que o atributo que você quer está nesse contexto. Eu posso tentar reproduzir o problema se você incluir mais informação (talvez todo o XSLT e um trecho do XML-fonte que contém os dados que não estão aparecendo)

Comment: Infelizmente não posso te informar o XML completo, pois é sharepoint e não tenho acesso a todo o conteúdo. O XSLT é muito extenso e não é preciso adiciona-lo aqui, apenas a chamada do estilo que estou atribuindo na consulta da biblioteca, que neste caso é o "Resultado-Lista"

Comment: Qual é o valor da variável `$Rows`? Qual o contexto do seu template? O que tem no `match` dele?

Comment: O problema não é $Rows, pois existem outros valores dentro deste `<xsl:for-each>` e o dados são retornados corretamente. Talvez o problema seja na validação da coluna do tipo "Imagem de Publicação", mas infelizmente, ainda não encontrei o que pode estar causando. Além do mais exportei a WebPart e adicionei no campo CommonViewFields a coluna @PublishingRollupImage (em caso de dúvidas) e mesmo assim ela não é exibida

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de comparar, você está atribuindo o valor `''` à variável `PublishingRollupImage`. Para verificar se está preenchida, basta fazer assim:

```
<xsl:when test="@PublishingRollupImage">
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Eu já tentei jogar o `<xsl:value-of select="@PublishingRollupImage"  />` fora do `<xsl:choose>` e não retorna nada

Comment: @LuannaIozzi isso é evidência de que então o problema não está na consulta em si, mas no valor armazenado em `PublishingRollupImage`. O que está armazenado nesse campo?

Comment: Adicionei uma imagem, consultando a biblioteca de imagens deste subsite e selecionando a desejada. A coluna esta como Opcional no SP

Answer (score 1):

É difícil oferecer uma solução em XSLT sem saber a estrutura dos dados de entrada, e sem saber exatamente o contexto em que o processamento ocorre, portanto esta resposta está baseada em várias suposições.

Eu pesquisei um pouco sobre sharepoint e descobri que o atributo `PublishingRollupImage` pode conter (ou sempre contém) XML embutido como texto cru. Isto não vai fazer diferença na hora de testar, mas terá que ser considerado na hora de exibir. Você terá que imprimir o resultado usando `disable-output-escaping` se quiser gerar XML.

Quanto ao teste que você fez, @Renan está certo: o teste `test="@PublishingRollupImage = ''"` testa se um atributo `PublishingRollupImage` existe e contém a string vazia, enquanto que usar simplesmente `test="@PublishingRollupImage`" testa se o atributo *existe*. São coisas diferentes.

Eu criei este XML de teste, que talvez seja similar ao que você está recebendo em que há três elementos `<Row>`. Um que contém um atributo `PublishingRollupImage` contendo XML embutido, outro que contém o atributo com uma string vazia, e finalmente um que *não* contém o atributo:

```xml
<root>
    <Row ID="1" Style="Resultado-Lista"
        Title="Imagem 1"
        PublishingRollupImage="&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;/PublishingImages/imagem.jpg&quot; style=&quot;border:px solid&quot; /&gt;" />
    <Row ID="2" Style="Resultado-Lista"
        Title="Imagem Faltando"
        PublishingRollupImage="" />
    <Row ID="3" Style="Resultado-Lista"
        Title="Não é imagem" />
</root>
```

Processei esse documento fonte na folha de estilos abaixo (que incluiu os três `Row` na variável `Rows`):

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="//Row"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="$Rows[1]/@Style='Resultado-Lista'">
               <ul>
                   <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                       <li>
                           <a href="/{@FileRef}" title="2014-05-26 - {@Title}">
                               <xsl:choose>
                                   <xsl:when test="(@PublishingRollupImage = '')">
                                       <img src="/Util/Imagens/Conteudo/sem-imagem-noticia.jpg" />
                                   </xsl:when>
                                   <xsl:otherwise>
                                       <xsl:value-of select="@PublishingRollupImage" disable-output-escaping="yes"  />
                                   </xsl:otherwise>
                               </xsl:choose>
                           </a>
                       </li>
                   </xsl:for-each>
               </ul>
           </xsl:when>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

E o resultado foi:

```xml
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="/" title="2014-05-26 - Imagem 1"><img alt="" src="/PublishingImages/imagem.jpg" style="border:px solid" /></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="/" title="2014-05-26 - Imagem Faltando">
         <img src="/Util/Imagens/Conteudo/sem-imagem-noticia.jpg"/>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="/" title="2014-05-26 - Não é imagem"/>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Coloquei um **[XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/b4GWVj)** aqui com o código do exemplo acima, que você pode testar em tempo real.

Veja se isto ajuda a encontrar a solução do seu problema.